# C++ cannot open source file "time.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, time.h

I am trying to use clocks to measure the time of the running program in Visual Studio 2015 (x64) with C++ on Windows in Debug x64 mode.

I get errors in these lines:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
```

The errors messages say:

> cannot open source file "time.h"
>
> cannot open source file "sys/timeb.h"

What path do I have to add to include directories in order to fix this error?

Comment: try `#include <ctime>`

Comment: also, consider the <chrono> library

Comment: I tried `#include <ctime>` but the same message shows up: `cannot open source file "ctime.h"`. The program used to run on a different machine, so I think it could work by adding the right path to include.

Comment: No it's the same Windows 10 x64

Comment: @ThomasSablik actually the code was for both Windows and Linux, so maybe I should just comment the line (`#include <sys/timeb.h>`) as it's not needed on Windows.

Comment: I found it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftime-ftime32-ftime64?view=vs-2019 You should accept the answer since it solved your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `#include <ctime>`

Refer to this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/

time.h is used is C not C++.

Comment: I tried `#include <ctime>` but the same message shows up: `cannot open source file "ctime.h"`

Comment: Yep. .h was C convention I guess. More or less all headers are without the .h now with C++. Try it without the .h

Comment: Ok `#include <ctime>` doesn't have the error anymore, but there is still this error: `identifier "clock_t" is undefined`

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad That's completely different question and not answerable with the provided information.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad [`std::clock_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock_t)?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius no that doesn't exist. clock_t should be in ctime

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad "_clock_t should be in ctime_" Yes..? Did you read the documentation link, that I provided? It's in `std` namespace, in `ctime` header.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius but when I type `std::clock_t` it says: `namespace "std" has no member "clock_t"`

Answer (score 1):

read this it explain that your method is POSIX, so your path to the sys/time.h must be set well

but there are 2 others way for : how to get time in milliseconds with cpp

https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/how-to-get-time-in-milliseconds-cpp/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32305205)